# Add upload/processing status bar/throbber

Tags: php, forms, file, drupal, menu

I am new to Drupal/web development and I have been trying to create a module to add files upload menu. Once the files are uploaded, they undergo processing and a message is displayed upon completion of the process. Everything works well but I would like to add a processing progress bar/throbber from the tile Submit button is selected to when the final output is displayed. I am clueless on how to implement this. Any help is appreciated
Here's part of the code I used:

```
//Before this part of the code, there is function to create Menu ($items[])
function g_p_proc_form($form, &$form_state, $values) {
    $form['#attributes']['enctype'] = 'multipart/form-data';
    $form['filter'] = array (
        "#type" => "fieldset",
        "#title" => t("File Process <BR> "),
        "#collapsible" => TRUE,
    );
  // without this attribute, upload may fail on submit
    $form['#attributes']['enctype'] = 'multipart/form-data';
    $form['filter']['file'] = array(
        // '#title' => t('File processing'),
        '#type'  => 'file',
        '#name' => 'files[]',
        '#description' => t('Select Submit to start processing the file'),
        '#type'  => 'file'),
        '#upload_location' => 'public://',
        '#attributes' => array('multiple' => 'multiple'),
    );

    $form['filter']['submit_upload'] = array(
        '#type'  =>  'submit', 
        '#value' =>  t('Submit'),

    );


    // drupal_set_message(t("in fn"));

    return $form;
}

function g_p_proc_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
    try{
        $number_file = count($_FILES['files']['name']);
        $f_name = array();
        for ($i=0; $i<$number_file;$i++)
        {
            $file = file_save_upload($i, array('file_validate_extensions' => array('pdf PDF')), 'public://', FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);
            $f_name[] = $_FILES['files']['name'][$i]; //[]
        }
            }catch (Exception $error){
        echo 'Exception: ',  $error->getMessage(), "\n";
    }
    $n_f = count($f_name);
    drupal_set_message(t('Number of files: !n_f', array('!number_f'=>$n_f)));
    $fn_name = 'g_p';
    $fn_call = $fn_name($f_name);
function g_p($f_name=array()){
    $curr_l = getcwd();
    chdir('My file processing PHP script location ');
    $n_f = count($f_name);
    $shell_command = shell_exec("file_processing_php_script_name.php");
    //header("Location: "Current file processing module menu site"); //Commented out
    drupal_set_message($shell_command);
    chdir($curr_l);
}
```

As it can be seen from the code, I process the files upon upload and display the output message after processing. I would like to add a throbber/processing-progress bar from the time Submit is selected to the time the output is displayed, after the files are processed. How can I achieve this? Again, please understand that I am new to web development/Drupal and am not very proficient in terms/commands used in them.
forms files

Comment: You will need javascript/ajax to implement throbber. PHP alone cannot be used to implement this feature. Throbber is implemented in the client side script. You may refer this blog https://chromatichq.com/blog/creating-custom-progress-throbber-drupal

Comment: @Chilarai Thanks for the info, is there any good Javascript tutorial where I can learn about implementation of throbber?

Comment: Refer the link above for drupal. For a good starting point for php, javascript based throbber, refer this https://tutorial.techaltum.com/javascript-ajax.html